# How can I tell if a point is on a quadratic Bézier curve within a given tolerance?

Tags: contains, point, bezier

I'm writing a library for Bézier curves. I already can calculate the curve as a collection of connected points to a given resolution, but I now need to do the reverse; detect whether a given point is on the curve within a given tolerance (e.g. `0.0001`). **Is there a simple mathematical function that can do this?**

Please phrase your answer in the form of a function that takes in three parameters: the `x` and `y` coordinates and a tolerance (distance from curve still considered "on" it), and which outputs a Boolean value. This will make it more generally useful to others. For example, such a function in Swift would have the signature `func isOnCurve(x: Float, y: Float, tolerance: Float) -> Bool`

Comment: Short answer: no, because you're using IEEE floats, not perfect mathematircs. So, what you really want is an evaluation that tells you *how close to the curve* your point is, so that you can decide whether "close enough" means "on"; for instance a distance of 0.1 is pretty much "on the curve" as far as pixel-rendered curves are concerned. Or do what @fang suggests, but then you still need to see which *actual* points the `tx` and `ty` values yield, and what the distance is between those, and your own point.

Comment: As secondary comment: which language are you using, because it is incredibly likely that there already exist Bezier curve libraries for it, and your efforts would be better spent using those and help improve them if they are deficient in certain contexts =)

Comment: Thanks for the note, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans! If it helps, I'll be using the same algorithm for `BigDecimal`s. Also, this is in **Kotlin**.

Comment: As long as you understand that even with BigDecimal, you still won't get exact numbers due to rounding, especially if you're going to be checking whether integer pixel coordinates lie on a real coordinates curve. As Kotlin targets the JVM, do you have access to the java subsystem such that you can import things like `java.graphics2d` classes?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I do, but I'm also targeting Kotlin for JavaScript and Kotlin Native

Comment: I assume you've asked this over on https://kotlinlang.org/community then, too? Any useful answers you got there that you can write an answer with here?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had no reason to; this should be a language-agnostic algorithm.

Comment: that makes no sense. Of course it's language agnostic, but different languages make it easier or harder to implement, so if you're looking at using Kotlin why not also find out if it's *already supported*, and if the answer is "yes", you're done. And if it's "no", that's pretty valuable information you can add to this question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's not supported in Kotlin, as kotlin-stdlib is as minimal as possible so doesn't include such things as Bézier curves. Anything in Java can't be used because I'll cross-compile to JS and native.

Comment: Is there no community around Kotlin that's busy writing the utility libraries/modules/packages/whateverKotlinCallThem? Because if it's not in Kotlin native, this problem may already be solved by someone else in the form of a library. That said: build a LUT, then find the **one or more points** that match your discrete x/y coordinate.

Comment: I am among that community, building this library! This will go in [my BézierPath class](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Blue-Base/blob/master/JVM/src/org/bh/tools/base/math/geometry/BezierPath.kt). I want the API to be `pathObject.contains(somePoint, tolerance)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could exploit the "distance to curve" method described over at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#projections, but this will find a single `t` value for any coordinate. For "is this point on the curve?" checks, that's fine (multiple `t` values do not change the answer; 0 is off-curve, 1 is on-curve, 2 or more is still on-curve).

Sample the curve at a few (relatively close-spaced) values for `t` (which I assume for efficiency you already do in order to only compute draw coordinates once, rather than every time the curve needs to be drawn), and then with the closest `t` that yields, start walking the curve, reducing the distance until you've found the minimal distance (how you walk is up to you: you can do a coarse-to-fine walk, or start off fine, or determine how far to jump based on the curve tangent, etc).

Then your result is literally just `return minDistance <= tolerance`.

Answer (score 0):

For a quadratic Bezier curve defined as

> C(t) = P0(1-t)^2+2P1t(1-t)+P2t^2 = P0+2(P1-P0)t+(P0-2P1+P2)t^2,

for a given point Q to lie on C(t) there must exist a solution for t between 0 and 1 that satisfies

> (P0-Q)+2(P1-P0)t+(P0-2P1+P2)t^2 = 0

Therefore, you can try to find the common real root for the following two equations

> (P0x-2P1x+2P2x)t^2+2(P1x-P0x)t+(P0x-Qx) = 0 
>   (P0y-2P1y+2P2y)t^2+2(P1y-P0y)t+(P0y-Qy) = 0

If such a common real root exist and it is between 0 and 1, it means point Q lies on the curve.

For cubic Bezier curve, you can follow this procedure in a similar way but you will have to find the roots for a cubic equation.

Comment: note that this is a great answer for a maths question, but not sufficient for a programming question: in an IEEE float domain, there is almost never a perfect solution, with points that "should" lie on a curve according to the maths not doing so. So you still need an epsilon check; either by evaluating this, and then seeing how far from the original point the coordinates at the found `tx` and `ty` values are, or you need to instead compute the distance of the point to the curve, and make an epsilon based decision on whether that distance is small enough to treat the point as "on the curve"

Comment: Can you phrase your answer in the form of a function that takes in two parameters (x and y) and a tolerance (distance from curve still considered "on") and outputs a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the parameter on the curve which is closest to the point, then you can find the distance.  If you have a bezier curve B(t), and a point P, then solve

> (P-B(t))⋅B'(t) = 0.

For a quadratic bezier this gives a cubic equation which can be solved analytically.  Alternatively you can use a iterative solver.  The minimal distance is then ||P-B(t)||.

Comment: Can you phrase your answer in the form of a function that takes in two parameters (x and y) and a tolerance (distance from curve still considered "on") and outputs a boolean?

Comment: The above formula gives you an analytic function, however it may not be what you want.  Due to rounding errors the result may not be very accurate, even when using a stable cubic root solver, because conversion from the bernstein basis to the power basis is not stable.  For instance, here is a paper that describes an iterative method for finding the point projection: http://www.geometrie.tugraz.at/wallner/sproj.pdf  You formula then becomes ||P - closest(B, P)|| < tol, where closest returns the point projection if one exists.

Comment: I'm not very concerned about rounding errors. Is there any way to turn this into `f(x, y, tolerance): boolean`?

Comment: Is your curve a constant?

Comment: In that it never changes, yes.